# Finding the expected value of the sum of N rolls.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, statistics

Question: A fair die is rolled once producing the number N.  Now that die is rolled N times.  Find the expected value of the sum of those N rolls.

I have been working on some practice problems, and this one in particular really stumps me.  I know that the chance of rolling N number on any fair die is $\frac16$. However, this appears to be the point where I get stuck.

An explanation of how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In plain words:*

As you noted, $N$ has an equal chance of landing on any number from $1$ to $6$. Intuitively, the overall expectation should be the average of the expected value of the sum under each case of $N$.

Pretend you are in the case $N=1$, and compute the expected value of the sum of the $N$ rolls.
Do the same for the other cases $N=2,\ldots,6$. Then average these  together.

---

*In math speak:*

Let $X$ be the sum of the $N$ rolls.
\begin{align}
E[X]
&= E[E[X \mid N]]
\\
&= \frac{1}{6} E[X \mid N=1] + \frac{1}{6} E[X \mid N=2] + \cdots + \frac{1}{6} E[X \mid N=6].
\end{align}

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you correctly.  We know that N takes on the values 1,2,...,6.  We know that p(x)=$\frac16$ for each of the values that N can take on.  We also know that the sum of the values that N can take on is 21.  So lets take N=1 for the example, $\frac16$ E[X|N=1] = $\frac{21}{6}=\frac{7}{2}$.  Since N=1 was the value of the roll, we only roll N=1 times to and sum those values.  Then if I am following correctly, we continue to do this for all 6 possible values of N and sum those all up.  Please let me know if this all makes since.  I can clarify my meaning further is not.

Comment: If $N=1$ you roll once, so $E[X \mid N=1]$ is the expected value of one roll, which is $7/2$. So $\frac{1}{6} E[X \mid N=1] = \frac{7}{12}$.

Comment: HA!, I did forget about the $\frac16$ in the front.  My fault.  Alright, so then continuing for N=2 you would obtain $\frac{49}{144}$, and you would add that to the $\frac{7}{12}$ that we obtained when N=1.  Then, if I followed correctly, this would continue through the 6 variations that N can take on.  Is that correct?

Comment: It seems like you just squared $7/12$ to get $49/144$, which is not right. The expected value of two rolls will be $7/2 + 7/2$.

Comment: Actually, I mean't to add 7/12 to another 7/12 not multiply so that was my first error (been working not this problem way too long tonight if I am making those kinds of errors). But then I was going to add that to the first 7/12 to have a total of 3 7/12 for the first 2 rolls but that's defiantly not what you were saying it seems. I defiantly was not following correctly.  But now, it seems that this question was being way over thought by myself, and all I would have to do is add 7/2 up 6 times, and then multiply it by 1/6 to get the final answer.  If I followed you that time then I thank you!

Comment: Ultimately the answer becomes 7/2 which makes sense. Thanks for your time before.

Comment: @Chris That is not right either. It is $\frac{1}{6} \cdot 1 \cdot 3.5 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 2 \cdot 3.5 + \cdots + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 6 \cdot 3.5$.

Comment: Oh, well dang!  Thank you so much!